# Having two or more Library Projects and the Main Project in Android Development

Tags: android, android-library

I added johannilsson-android-actionbar as a library to my project. It worked well, and everything was good for me. But recently, I have added the uitableView as a library and got this error:

> /--mypath--/actionbar/res/values/attrs.xml:19: error: Attribute "tittle" has already been defined

And the R is not Known, so I cannot reference my XML. I have ADT 17 and Eclipse 3.7. I tried to remove the uitableview, and the project works fine, no Errors, and R is OK.

Comment: As you have got their source code on hand, at the meantime, just rename the title attribute from any one of library project to something else.

Answer (score 0):

The authors of libraries need to take steps to avoid collisions on resource IDs. The authors of your libraries have not, apparently.

One possibility is to switch from johannilsson-android-actionbar to [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com) and see if you have better luck.

Comment: Thanks, i've downloaded ActionBarSherlock, let me try it, Because i want 2 use both the thiagolocatelli-android-uitableview and the actionBar, i'll update upon success,

Comment: This is definitely a bug in SDK, **the resource collisions is supposed to be automatically detected and handled by SDK** (using relative priority `android.library.reference.X`), referred from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects): _When two libraries referenced from an application define the same resource ID, the tools select the resource from the library with higher priority and discard the other._

Comment: And [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html#ReferencingLibraryProject): _If you are adding references to multiple libraries, note that you can set their relative priority (and merge order) by manually editing the project.properties file and adjusting the each reference's .n index as appropriate._

Comment: YES it works, just renamed the attribute tittle, Now No collision, thanks yorkw, thanks CommonsWare, i also tried to use ActionBarSherlock in demo Project, Now im becomming a Guru in UI, thanks everyone, u saved me, now i can present my Project @school, with Awesome UI